# spacing=true + ragged2e produces bad minipages

Tags: microtype, ragged2e

I understand the `spacing=true` option in `microtype` is considered "experimental". However, for my document it does improve the appearance of the document -- with the dramatic exception of certain minipages when `ragged2e` is also used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage[spacing=true]{microtype}

\newenvironment{mybox}{
\begin{minipage}[\textheight]{\linewidth}
\begin{mdframed}
}{
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the best solution (aside from the default `spacing=false`)?

Comment: I get no issue if I add the `\RaggedRight` declaration at the start of the `mdframed` environment.

Comment: That's true for this example; however, in general that didn't seem to solve the problem. I'll try to produce an example.

Comment: Well, `microtype` warns you that with `ragged2e` something bad can happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `microtype` package issues a warning:

```
Package microtype Warning: You are using the `ragged2e' package.
(microtype)                Adjustment of interword spacing may lead to
(microtype)                undesired results when used with `ragged2e'.
(microtype)                In this case, disable the `spacing' option.
```

However, there's no wrong output if I restate `\RaggedRight` at the beginning of the `mdframed` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage[spacing=true]{microtype}

\newenvironment{mybox}
 {\begin{minipage}[\textheight]{\linewidth}
  \begin{mdframed}\RaggedRight}
 {\end{mdframed}\end{minipage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

It's not clear what's the role of the `minipage` wrapper, though.

[image]

If you want that the framed box is not split across pages, just add the `nobreak` option.

```
\newenvironment{mybox}
 {\begin{mdframed}[nobreak]\RaggedRight}
 {\end{mdframed}}
```

This also avoids the need of `\noindent`.